# Rails 4: add exemption for after_update in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an after_update callback in my model

```
after_update :do_something
```

However, I don't want the method to be called after an object has been created. Is is possibe to add an exemption to after_update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails has many different [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks). When you create an object `after_create` and `after_save` are called. When you update an existing object, `after_update` and `after_save` are called.

`after_create` is used only on creation as `after_update` is only for updating existing objects. `after_save` runs on both cases, after the proper create/update callback.

If you don't want the method to be called only after an object has been created you should use `after_create` instead.

You could define as many callbacks as you need

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :one_method
  after_create :another_method
  after_update :one_more_method_only_for_updates

  def one_method
  end

  def another_method
  end

  def one_more_method_only_for_updates
  end
end
```

Comment: My question was probably not clear enough. I have a method that I only want to call whenever an object has been created, and another method that I want to call whenever an object has been updated, but not created.

Comment: You can have many callbacks. I've updated the example to show that

Comment: So when I understand you correctly then you are saying that the after_update callback doesn't get called after an object gets created. However, in my case it does seem to get called.

Comment: No, it doesn't get called, _unless you save the object twice_ on the same request... See the link I posted for details about the callbacks http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks